# Updating ResourceTheme not reflecting on TextBox BorderBrush in UWP App

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I am updating App `ThemeResource` from code-behind. It's changing App Theme but TextBox `BorderBrush` Property is not getting updated.

I have a custom resource `MyBorderBrush` for `Dark` and `Light` Theme which I have defined in my App.xaml.

Xaml:

```
<StackPanel>
            <TextBox PlaceholderText="My PlaceholderText" Height="100" Width="500" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Style="{StaticResource NoHighlightTextBoxStyle}" BorderBrush="{Binding IsError, Converter={ThemeResource BorderBrushColorConverter}}" VerticalAlignment="Center" ></TextBox>
            <Button Content="Change Theme" Click="Button_Click"></Button>
</StackPanel>
```

Code Behind:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.RequestedTheme = this.RequestedTheme == ElementTheme.Light ? ElementTheme.Dark : ElementTheme.Light;
}
```

**EDIT**

I thought that the issue might be with code behind or defining the resources, so I just shared the minimal code in order to reproduce the issue. But as pointed by @Ashiq the issue is with TextBox. Actually, the thing is that I have `BorderBrush` property bound to a converter for getting the correct value, but on changing the theme Border color is not getting changed.

Converter:

```
 public class BorderBrushColorConverter : IValueConverter
 {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
        {
            var isError = value as bool? ?? false;
            return isError
                ? Application.Current.Resources["MyBorderBrushMandatory"] as SolidColorBrush
                : Application.Current.Resources["MyBorderBrush"] as SolidColorBrush;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
}
```

App.xaml

```
<ResourceDictionary x:Key="Light" >
             <Color x:Key="MyBorder">#6b6b6b</Color>
             <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MyBorderBrush" Color="{ThemeResource MyBorder}" />

              <Color x:Key="MyBorderMandatory">#ff0000</Color>
              <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MyBorderBrushMandatory" Color="{ThemeResource MyBorderMandatory}" />
</ResourceDictionary>
<ResourceDictionary x:Key="Dark" >
               <Color x:Key="MyBorder">#c85332</Color>
               <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MyBorderBrush" Color="{ThemeResource MyBorder}" />

               <Color x:Key="MyBorderMandatory">#FFD700</Color>
               <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MyBorderBrushMandatory" Color="{ThemeResource MyBorderMandatory}" />
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Comment: Did you used INotifyPropertyChanged event to IsError property ?

Comment: Yes, I have used `INotifyPropertyChanged` for IsError.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not bind a Brush to the `TextBox` 's `BorderBrush`, that means you have set a fixed Brush value to the `BorderBrush`. When you use the `Binding` and `IValueConverter` in your xaml, it assigns the `SolidColorBrush` value in "MyBorderBrushMandatory" or "MyBorderBrush" resource to the `BorderBrush`, it is a static value and would not change base on the theme's change. In short, it is similar that you set a Red fixed `SolidColorBrush` to the `BorderBrush` and doesn't matter with dynamic theme resource.

If you want the `BorderBrush` of `TextBox` to change when you change the theme, you can just replace your xaml `TextBox` binding code with theme resources reference:

```
<TextBox PlaceholderText="My PlaceholderText" Height="100" Width="500"
         HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
         BorderBrush="{ThemeResource MyBorderBrushMandatory}"
         VerticalAlignment="Center" ></TextBox>
```

On the other way, if you want to use binding to change the `BorderBrush` of `TextBox` when the theme changed, you should make the `IsError` property implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, meanwhile, you should subscribe the [ActualThemeChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.frameworkelement.actualthemechanged) event to change the `IsError` property's value to get the value of `SolidColorBrush` from your `BorderBrushColorConverter` then update the UI.

The following is a sample that depend on your above code:

MainPage.xaml:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <local:BorderBrushColorConverter x:Key="BorderBrushColorConverter"/>
</Page.Resources>

<StackPanel>
    <TextBox PlaceholderText="My PlaceholderText" Height="100" Width="500" HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
             BorderBrush="{Binding IsError, Converter={StaticResource BorderBrushColorConverter}}"
             VerticalAlignment="Center" ></TextBox>
    <Button Content="Change Theme" Click="Button_Click"></Button>
</StackPanel>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page,INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;
        this.ActualThemeChanged += MainPage_ActualThemeChanged;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void MainPage_ActualThemeChanged(FrameworkElement sender, object args)
    {
        IsError = !IsError;
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.RequestedTheme = this.RequestedTheme == ElementTheme.Light ? ElementTheme.Dark : ElementTheme.Light;
    }

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string Name)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(Name));
        }
    }

    private bool? isError=true;
    public bool? IsError
    {
        get
        {
            return isError;
        }
        set
        {
            isError = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("IsError");
        }
    }

}
```

---Update---

Let's talk about your sample.
Firstly, we all know that you set the `TextBox` 's `BorderBrush` by get the Application Resources from the App.xaml. In your Page2.xaml.cs, you use the following code,

```
this.RequestedTheme = App.SelectedTheme;
```

This code only set the UI theme that is used by the UIElement (and its child elements) for resource determination, that is to say, the code only set the page's theme but not the Application. Your app runs  using the theme set by the user in Windows settings by default(Settings > Personalization > Colors > Choose your default app mode), and you can also set the app's [RequestedTheme](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.application.requestedtheme#Windows_UI_Xaml_Application_RequestedTheme) property to override the user default and specify which theme is used.

As the **[Remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.application.requestedtheme?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(Windows.UI.Xaml.Application.RequestedTheme)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETCore%2CVersion%3Dv5.0)%3Bk(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue#remarks)** part:

> The theme can only be set when the app is started, not while it’s running. Attempting to set RequestedTheme while the app is running throws an exception (NotSupportedException for Microsoft .NET code). If you give the user an option to pick a theme that's part of app UI, you must save the setting in the app data and apply it when the app is restarted.

So when you change the page's `RequestedTheme`, this will not affect the Application's [RequestedTheme](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.application.requestedtheme#Windows_UI_Xaml_Application_RequestedTheme), it is still the Application's [RequestedTheme](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.application.requestedtheme#Windows_UI_Xaml_Application_RequestedTheme) you set on your sample's App.xaml, as the code,

```
RequestedTheme="Light"
```

So when you get use the code `Application.Current.Resources` to get the application resource, it still get the "Light" theme resource. It is different from that you use the [ThemeResource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/themeresource-markup-extension). For your this issue, theme resource is not what you want, you should set some different Color Brush in the resource, then get the different Color Brush resource base on your page's resource setting using [StaticResource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/staticresource-markup-extension).

---Update 2---

Here is a simple solution, just add Application resource in the App.xaml,

```
<Application.Resources>
        <Color x:Key="MyBorder">#6b6b6b</Color>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MyBorderBrush" Color="{StaticResource MyBorder}" />

        <Color x:Key="MyBorderMandatory">#ff0000</Color>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MyBorderBrushMandatory" Color="{StaticResource MyBorderMandatory}" />

        <Color x:Key="MyBorderDark">#c85332</Color>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MyBorderBrushDark" Color="{StaticResource MyBorderDark}" />

        <Color x:Key="MyBorderMandatoryDark">#FFD700</Color>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MyBorderBrushMandatoryDark" Color="{StaticResource MyBorderMandatoryDark}" />
...
</Application.Resources>
```

In the BorderBrushColorConverter.cs, change the `Convert` method,

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
{
    var isError = value as bool? ?? false;
    if (isError)
    {
        if (App.SelectedTheme == ElementTheme.Light)
        {
            return Application.Current.Resources["MyBorderBrushMandatory"] as SolidColorBrush;
        }
        else
        {
            return Application.Current.Resources["MyBorderBrushMandatoryDark"] as SolidColorBrush;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

In the Page2.xaml, change to static resource reference,

```
<TextBox PlaceholderText="My PlaceholderText" Height="100" Width="500"
         HorizontalAlignment="Center" Style="{StaticResource NoHighlightTextBoxStyle}"
         BorderBrush="{Binding IsError, Converter={StaticResource BorderBrushColorConverter}}" 
         VerticalAlignment="Center" ></TextBox>
```

Comment: Thanks. But here are few clarifications 1> IsError is a property which is updated based on some other data and not on theme changed 2> Also property change does not make any sense as theme change is done from another page(say settings) and navigating to these page does not take appropriate theme resource. I have created a sample to repro this issue which you can download it from [here](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AmazyQ-ydr33hIF577_0mLo1XH_2xA)

Comment: I have updated my answer with **Update** part. You can check it.

Comment: So, basically, when we use `ThemeResource` it will change the color when we update `RequestedTheme` but as in my case, I am updating it from `Application.Current.Resources["MyBorderBrush"]` it will still load the color based on the theme that was at App Startup, right? Also, I would like if you can post some code snippet on what I can do to solve my issue would be helpful

Comment: Yes, it is that. I add the update2 part as a simple solution, you can have a try.

Answer (score 1):

You are making dynamic theme changing at Runtime. So change StaticResource to ThemeResource. That's all.

from

```
BorderBrush="{StaticResource MyBorderBrush}"
```

to

```
BorderBrush="{ThemeResource MyBorderBrush}"
```

Thankyou.

Comment: Thanks, Please see my updated post. I would have created new SO thread but thought to update this as it's more relevant instead of creating another thread.